# My Keyboard Events not firing after I reference the stage to a menu class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm having a problem with this menu tutorial I followed from [ASGamer](http://asgamer.com/2009/making-a-complete-flash-game-menus-ui-screens-or-windows).  I have done and used most, if not all of the tutorials from that site.

Anyway my problem is their base menu class;

```
package com.game.scripts.menu
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;

    import com.caurina.transitions.Tweener;

    public class BaseMenu extends MovieClip
    {
        public var stageRef:Stage;
        public var loadNext:BaseMenu;

        public function BaseMenu()
        {
            alpha = 0;
        }

        public function Unload(loadMe:BaseMenu = null):void
        {
            if(loadMe != null)
            {
                loadNext = loadMe;
            }

            Tweener.addTween(this, {alpha:0, time:0.7, onComplete:Remove});
        }

        public function Remove():void
        {
            //dispatchEvent(new Event("menuRemoved"));
            if(stageRef.contains(this))
            {
                stageRef.removeChild(this);
            }

            if(loadNext != null)
            {
                loadNext.Load();
            }
        }

        public function Load():void
        {
            stageRef.addChild(this);
            Tweener.addTween(this, {alpha:1, time:0.7});
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I use the Remove() function, which is also used by the Unload() function, my stage.addEventListeners breaks.  Particularly my stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUpHandler) in another class does not execute at all.

Is there another way I can remove the menus without breaking the stage?  Or if you know of a better menu tutorial, a link would be greatly appreciated :D

**EDIT**
I just commented everything in the Remove() function and key handler is still not working.

**EDIT 2**
The first edit only applied to my MainMenu, my other menus seem fine.  I commented this part;

```
if(stageRef.contains(this))
{
    stageRef.removeChild(this);
}
```

and my KeyUpHandler works fine.  So I'm assuming that flash will not remove the movieclips for me, or will I be fine and it will be removed?

Comment: That is a pretty bad tutorial. Here is a very good one about building a complete game. http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/

Comment: I finally solved the problem.  For some reason the key up handler doesnt register unless i click on the screen after a new menu loads.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that the Sprite you are giving to the menu class for the stageRef has no reference after you call remove, and so get garbage collected, so you no longer get any key events.

Two suggestions:

- Make sure you are setting the appropriate value for the stageRef
- Make sure that you are using a strong reference in your keyboard listener to make sure the stage is not cleaned up.

Comment: What do you mean by strong reference?

Comment: The 5th param in addEventListener is useWeakReaference:Boolean, if you set that to false then you get a strong reference which ensure that the object you are listening too will not get garbage collected while you are listening : http://dispatchevent.org/mims/creating-weak-references-in-as3/

Comment: giving the key handler a strong reference still doesnt fix the problem.  The thing I really don't understand is why only the key handler is affected, everything else seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: come to think of it you don't need to do this if your BaseMenu is derived from sprite or MovieClip I am pretty sure. so just change stageRef.removeChild() to stage.removeChild()

your stageRef isn't actually pointing at the real stage. (sort of)

Also you should try to get used to using ADDED_TO_STAGE events.

```
package src 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MainDocument extends Sprite
    {
        private var myMenus:BaseMenu;

        public function MainDocument() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initMain);
        }

        private function initMain(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initMain);

            myMenus = new BaseMenu();
            addChild(myMenus);
        }

    }

}

package src 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class BaseMenu extends Sprite
    {
        public function BaseMenu() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initBanseMenu);
        }

        private function initBanseMenu(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initBanseMenu);

            trace(stage.stageHeight);
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see from the trace the stage is accessible without the reference.

This should also work just fine. (the actually stage is 'stage' not 'Stage' so make sure your sending 'stage' to your BaseMenu constructor.

```
public var stageRef:Stage;

public function BaseMenu(stageRef:Stage)
{
    this.stageRef = stageRef;
    alpha = 0;
}
```

---

Ok here you can put these files in a flashdevelop project or whatever your using and test it ;-).

```
package src 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class MainDocument extends Sprite
    {
        public var myMenuTest:BaseMenu;
        public var mySubMenuTest:SubMenu; 

        public function MainDocument() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initMain);
        }

        private function initMain(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initMain);

            myMenuTest = new BaseMenu(stage);
            myMenuTest.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            myMenuTest.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            //myMenuTest.Load(); // we can load our Main menu now if we want.

            mySubMenuTest = new SubMenu(stage);
            mySubMenuTest.x = 100;
            mySubMenuTest.y = 100;

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, handleKeyUp);
        }

        // for testing purposes.
        private function handleKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
                myMenuTest.Unload(mySubMenuTest);
            else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
                mySubMenuTest.Unload(myMenuTest);
            else
                trace(e.keyCode);
        }
    }
}

package src 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class BaseMenu extends Sprite
    {
        public var stageRef:Stage;
        public var loadNext:BaseMenu;

        public function BaseMenu(stageRef:Stage) 
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
        }

        public function Unload(loadMe:BaseMenu = null):void
        {
            if (loadMe != null)
            {
                loadNext = loadMe;
            }
            Remove(); // add your tween.
        }

        public function Load():void
        {
            // this is just so we can have something to see for the test.
            drawTest();
            stageRef.addChild(this);
            // add your tween
        }

        public function Remove():void
        {
            if (stageRef.contains(this))
                stageRef.removeChild(this);

            if (loadNext != null)
                loadNext.Load();
        }

        protected function drawTest():void
        {
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.lineStyle(1, 0);
            graphics.beginFill(0xccccff);
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}

package src 
{
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class SubMenu extends BaseMenu
    {
        public function SubMenu(stageRef:Stage) 
        {
            super(stageRef);
        }
    }
}
```

This should explain how what I meant works.
To test this program just load it up in debug mode and use Up or Down arrow keys to switch between the two menu classes. hitting any other key no matter what menu is up will trace the keyCode to standard out. (debug output window).
Obviously 1 class per file.
Hope this clears it up.

Comment: The base menu constructor doesn't take in a parameter because the classes that extend the base menu would get an error since they have the constructor with the stage parameter.  The Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE is already used on my main.as file do I need do that check in every class?

Comment: Using ADDED_TO_STAGE will guarantee that something is actually on the stage before you try to work with it. This is usually not an issue but some hard to debug problems can happen if your not careful with it.

Comment: The stageRef has to be referenced some how. You can't just say var stageRef:Stage it has to point to something. The fastest way is to send that reference when creating the object. Everything that extends BaseMenu will also need to have that reference. If you go the other route and use added_to_stage because baseMenu extends Sprite/MovieClip it will already have an internal reference to the stage like my above stage.stageHeight

Comment: These are really your only two options to have a clean reference to the stage. (well that I am aware of)

Comment: I tried making the changes to the BaseMenu class and I get a null reference from the extended menu classes.  If I was to do it the way you suggested I would have redo the entire menu system.  I updated my question stating that the if statement where I use stageRef to remove the menu was the problem and if there was a way to either go on with out it, or another method of removing the movieclip.

Comment: I did, I got an error in the Load() function with stage.addChild(this); it was a null object reference error #1009.  So in that class stage doesnt exsist and without stage just addChild is a parenting error #2024 can't be a child of itself.